# Probability for standard and non-standard cubes.

Tags: probability

The first player has an ordinary 1d6 cube. The second player has a non-standard cube, where on one of his faces, instead of one, is a dragon image. The goal of the game is to throw out the number more than the opponent. If a second player drops a dragon, he automatically wins. If both have the same number - it's a draw, and the game is repeated.
Is this game profitable for the first player, if his bet in this game is 2 times less than the rate of the second player?

My approach is to find the probability for each player. There are 36 variants. Five of them gives a draw, 10 of them gives win for a first player and 21 gives the win for second player. 
What formula is right $p(A)=\frac{10}{31}$ or  $p(A)=\frac{10}{36}+\frac{5}{36}\cdot( \frac{10}{36}+\frac{5}{36}\cdot(...))$ or other?

Comment: As ties do not have any effect on the ultimate outcome, ignore them.  Thus there are $31$ meaningful outcomes, $10$ of which are wins for player $1$, so $\frac {10}{31}$ is correct.

Comment: @lulu thanks. So is this game with bet 1:2 profitable for second player?

Comment: Not sure I understand the betting.  Are you saying that player $1$ puts up $X$, player $2$ puts up $2X$ with the winner taking all?  If so then player $1$ expects to gain $2X\times \frac {10}{31}-X\times \frac {21}{31}=-X\times \frac {1}{31}$, hence an expected loss for the first player.

Comment: one more question: is second formula is equial  $\frac{10}{31}$?

Comment: @lulu one more thanks.

Comment: Sure.  it is $\frac {10}{36}\times \left(1+\frac 5{36} + \left( \frac 5{36} \right)^2+\cdots\right)= \frac {10}{36}\times \left(\frac 1{1-\frac 5{36}}\right)=\frac {10}{36}\times \frac {36}{31}=\frac {10}{31}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

The two probabilities coincide and both are correct.  To see that they coincide we write:
$$\frac {10}{36}\times \left(1+\frac 5{36} + \left( \frac 5{36} \right)^2+\cdots\right)= \frac {10}{36}\times \left(\frac 1{1-\frac 5{36}}\right)=\frac {10}{36}\times \frac {36}{31}=\frac {10}{31}$$

To see that they are correct note that ties are irrelevant, there are $31$ equiprobable meaningful outcomes and the first player wins $10$ of these.

To answer the primary question we assume player $1$ puts up $X$ and player $2$ puts up $2X$ with the winner taking all.  Then Player $1$ expects:  $$2X\times \frac {10}{31}-X\times \frac {21}{31}=-X\times \frac {1}{31}$$

Thus Player $1$ is at a disadvantage.